# airplane probability question.

Tags: probability

If the probability of hitting the gas tank of an airplane by an anti-aircraft missile is 0.3, and that of the body of the plane is 0.4. Answer the following questions:

1-If 5 missiles were shot toward the plane, what is the probability of hitting the gas tank with two missiles and the body with two more.

2-how many missiles should be shot so the probability of hitting the gas tank would be 0.95.
can I use the bayes' rule?

Comment: The plane doesn't crash after being hit by a missile????

Comment: yes it will be crashed

Comment: And hence the plane will *never* get hit by two or more missiles.  Obviously, then, "the probability of hitting the gas tank with two missiles and the body with two more" is zero.

Comment: great, so what if it wasn't crashed?

Comment: What did you mean by "yes it will be crashed"?  Can't you make a much *better* question to address the fundamental mathematics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the outcomes of all the missile firings are independent, then the numbers of missiles hitting the gas tank, the body, and missing altogether follow a multinomial distribution:
$$ \mathrm{Prob}\left(G=g, B=b, M=m\right)=0.3^g\cdot0.4^b\cdot0.3^m{g+b+m\choose g\,b\, m}\ .$$
The probability of hitting both the gas tank and the body of the aircraft with *exactly* two missiles each (and therefore missing with the remaining one of the five) is therefore:
$$ 0.3^2\cdot0.4^2\cdot0.3\, \frac{5!}{2! 2! 1!} = 30\cdot0.00432 =.01296\ .$$
If you want the probability that both the gas tank and the body are hit by *at least* two missiles, you have to add to this the probabilities that three missiles hit the gas tank and two hit the body and that two hit the gas tank and three hit the body:
$$
 0.01296+0.3^3\cdot0.4^2{5\choose3\,2\,0}+ 0.3^2\cdot0.4^3\ {5\choose3\,2\,0}=0.11376
$$
The probability that $\ m\ $ missiles *all* miss the gas tank is $\ 0.7^m\ $, which you want to be (at most?) $\ 1-0.95=0.05\ $. Since $\ 0.7^8\approx 0.057\ $, and $\ 0.7^9\approx0.040\ $ eight missiles are not enough, but nine are.